# Load older messages of conversation

Tags: php, ajax

I'd like to display the messages between (two or more) users in a way (like facebook) that the newest ones are displayed at the bottom.
By default there are loaded 5 messages and on top a button "Show older" to show older messages without re-loading the page completely.

Example how it should look like:
http://jsfiddle.net/UEZ4G/1/

I have a database with all messages currently queried with `ORDER BY messages.send_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5` to get the 5 most recent messages. With PHP I output an unordered list with each message as a listitem in the order I like.

My question: How can i load the messages 6-10 to the beginning of the unordered list after clicking on "show older"?

**EDIT** to be more specific: I want to make an AJAX call to a script that loads the next 5 messages. So if currently there are displayed the messages 0 to 5, the script should send back the messages loaded in `ORDER BY messages.send_date DESC LIMIT 5, 5` and put them at the beginning of the list.

Comment: This question is a bit broad. The obvious answer is run the next query  as `ORDER BY messages.send_date DESC LIMIT 5, 10`. You need to be more specific as to where you are stuck.

Comment: Most likely you will want to add the additional messages with JavaScript after your successful AJAX request

Comment: Okay I got it working. I send back the results from `ORDER BY messages.send_date DESC LIMIT 5, 5` as listitems and on the unordered list, I found the jquery function `$('#loadmore').prepend(return_data);`